# C# equalent to perl `pack("v",value)` while packing some values into `byte[]`

Tags: c#, perl, byte, arrays, bytecode

I am trying to replicate behavior of a perl script in my c# code. When we convert any value into the `Byte[]` it should look same irrespective of the language used. SO

I have this function call which looks like this in perl:

`$diag_cmd = pack("V", length($s_part)) . $s_part;`

where  `$s_par` is defined in following function. It is taking the `.pds` file at the location `C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\DIAG\PwrDB\offtarget\data\get_8084_gpio.pds`

```
$s_part = 

    sub read_pds
    {
       my $bin_s;
       my $input_pds_file = $_[0];
      open(my $fh, '<', $input_pds_file) or die "cannot open file $input_pds_file";
      {
        local $/;
        $bin_s = <$fh>;
      }

  close($fh);
  return $bin_s;

}
```

My best guess is that this function is reading the `.pds` file and turning it into a Byte array.

Now, I tried to replicate the behavior into c# code like following

```
static byte[] ConstructPacket()
{
    List<byte> retval = new List<byte>();         
    retval.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\DIAG\PwrDB\offtarget\data\get_8084_gpio.pds"));
    return retval.ToArray();
}
```

But the resulting byte array does not look same. Is there any special mechanism that I have to follow to replicate the behavior of  `pack("V", length($s_part)) . $s_part` ?

Comment: The `pack` documentation appears to say `V` equates to unsigned 32-bit (`uint` in C#) integers... not bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon Whitehead mentioned the template character `V` tells `pack` to pack your values into unsigned long (32-bit) integers (in little endian order). So you need to convert your bytes to a list (or array) of unsigned integers.

For example:

```
static uint[] UnpackUint32(string filename)
{
    var retval = new List<uint>();

    using (var filestream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var binaryStream = new System.IO.BinaryReader(filestream))
        {
            var pos = 0;
            while (pos < binaryStream.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                retval.Add(binaryStream.ReadUInt32());
                pos += 4;
            }
        }
    }

    return retval.ToArray();
}
```

And call this function:

```
var list = UnpackUint32(@"C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\DIAG\PwrDB\offtarget\data\get_8084_gpio.pds");
```

### Update

If you wanna read one length-prefixed string or a list of them, you can use this function:

```
private string[] UnpackStrings(string filename)
{
    var retval = new List<string>();

    using (var filestream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var binaryStream = new System.IO.BinaryReader(filestream))
        {
            var pos = 0;
            while ((pos + 4) <= binaryStream.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                // read the length of the string
                var len = binaryStream.ReadUInt32();

                // read the bytes of the string
                var byteArr = binaryStream.ReadBytes((int) len);

                // cast this bytes to a char and append them to a stringbuilder
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var b in byteArr)
                    sb.Append((char)b);

                // add the new string to our collection of strings
                retval.Add(sb.ToString());

                // calculate start position of next value
                pos += 4 + (int) len;
            }
        }
    }

    return retval.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pack("V", length($s_part)) . $s_part
```

which can also be written as

```
pack("V/a*", $s_part)
```

creates a length-prefixed string. The length is stored as a 32-bit unsigned little-endian number.

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------- ...
|  Length  |  Length  |  Length  |  Length  | Bytes
| ( 7.. 0) | (15.. 8) | (23..16) | (31..24) |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------- ...
```

This is how you recreate the original string from the bytes:

1. Read 4 bytes
2. If using a machine other than a little-endian machine,

   1. Rearrange the bytes into the native order.
3. Cast those bytes into an 32-bit unsigned integer.
4. Read a number of bytes equal to that number.
5. Convert that sequences of bytes into a string.

Some languages provide tools that perform more than one of these steps.

I don't know C#, so I can't write the code for you, but I can give you an example in two other languages.

In Perl, this would be written as follows:

```
sub read_bytes {
   my ($fh, $num_bytes_to_read) = @_;
   my $buf = '';
   while ($num_bytes_to_read) {
      my $num_bytes_read = read($fh, $buf, $num_bytes_to_read, length($buf));
      if (!$num_bytes_read) {
         die "$!\n" if !defined($num_bytes_read);
         die "Premature EOF\n";
      }

      $num_bytes_to_read -= $num_bytes_read;
   }

   return $buf;
}

sub read_uint32le { unpack('V', read_bytes($_[0], 4)) }
sub read_pstr { read_bytes($_[0], read_uint32le($_[0])) }

my $str = read_pstr($fh);
```

In C,

```
int read_bytes(FILE* fh, void* buf, size_t num_bytes_to_read) {
   while (num_bytes_to_read) {
      size_t num_bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, num_bytes_to_read, fh);
      if (!num_bytes_read)
         return 0;

      num_bytes_to_read -= num_bytes_read;
      buf += num_bytes_read;
   }

   return 1;
}

int read_uint32le(FILE* fh, uint32_t* p_i) {
   int ok = read_bytes(fh, p_i, sizeof(*p_i));
   if (!ok)
      return 0;

   { /* Rearrange bytes on non-LE machines */
      const char* p = (char*)p_i;
      *p_i = ((((p[3] << 8) | p[2]) << 8) | p[1]) << 8) | p[0];
   }

   return 1;
}

char* read_pstr(FILE* fh) {
   uint32_t len;
   char* buf = NULL;
   int ok;

   ok = read_uint32le(fh, &len);
   if (!ok)
      goto ERROR;

   buf = malloc(len+1);
   if (!buf)
      goto ERROR;

   ok = read_bytes(fh, buf, len);
   if (!ok)
      goto ERROR;

   buf[len] = '\0';
   return buf;

ERROR:
   if (p)
      free(p);

   return NULL;
}


char* str = read_pstr(fh);
```